# re-use similar luigi tasks

Tags: python, luigi

I have a luigi task which reads a .sql file and outputs to BigQuery.

My question is there any way I can reuse that same task with a different .sql file without having to copy the whole luigi task, i.e. I want to create instances of a template luigi task.

```
class run_sql(luigi.task):
    sql_file = 'path/to/sql/file'  # This is the only bit of code that changes 
    def complete(self):
        ...
    def requires(self):
        ...
    def run(self):
        ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building off of @matagus' answer, you can also subclass `RunSql` to define a sql file, using the `complete()`, `requires()`, and `run()` methods of the parent class.

```
class RunSqlFile(RunSql):
    sql_file = '/path/to/file.sql`
```

Or you can use the `@property` decorator to reference attributes of the `RunSql` class. I often do this to set a directory, or other configuration data, in the parent class, then reference them in subclasses.

```
class RunSql(luigi.Task):
    sql_file = luigi.Parameter()

    def get_file(self, name):
        default_dir = '/path/to/sql/dir'
        return os.path.join(default_dir, name)

   def requires(self):
        ...


class RunSqlFile(RunTask):

    @property
    def sql_file(self):
        return self.get_file("query.sql")
```

And that will act as if you'd instantiated the class with `--sql-file /path/to/sql/dir/query.sql`

Answer (score 1):

Just use [a parameter](https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parameters.html#parameter-types) to specify the path to the file. Something like this:

```
class RunSql(luigi.task):

    sql_file = luigi.Parameter()

    def complete(self):
        ...

    def requires(self):
        ...

    def run(self):
        ...
```

In order to access the value of the param just use `self.sql_file` in your code.

After that you may run your task this way:

```
luigi RunSql --sql-file path/to/file.sql
```

Comment: OK that makes sense. What if I have multiple .sql files? I would like to build the pipeline in such a way I do not have to repeat the code and change just the sql_file parameter. Would you then suggest having a list of .sql files and then the luigi task executes all of them?

Comment: You may have task that reads all *.sql the files in a directory by example and then triggers a `RunSql` task per each of them.

Comment: @HemeshPatel please mark the answer as valid if so. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers